# Unity 2d 5 Collider not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Using Unity 5.0.1f1

I'm trying to make it so that when I shoot, if it hits an invisible object it destroys it, but when it collides nothing happens. Here is the code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){

    Destroy (col.gameObject);
    Debug.Log ("find");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard for me to give you an answer given the little information that you are providing. But, the most possible solutions to your problem are:

1. Attaching a Rigidbody component to one of the colliding objects.
2. Making the object which will be destroyed have a normal collider attached and the other object must have a trigger collider attached.
3. Make sure that all of the Colliders/Triggers and Rigidbodies you use are 2D. That is, Rigidbody2D and Collider2D. Because you are using the `void OnTriggerEnter2D` method.
4. Make sure that the colliding objects are in layers which collide with each other. You can check which layer collides with each layer by going to Edit-->Project Settings-->Physics2D (Or Physics if you end up using 3D Physics).

Hope this helps!